# Puppet not pulling in changes - Could not request certificate getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: puppet

I hope this is a simple fix and as background I have no experience with Puppet or Foreman.

The set up:

- two puppet master nodes running on ec2
- many other ec2 nodes running puppet modules
- foreman running on ec2
- gitlab running on ec2

The puppet modules are all defined in gitlab. Normally when a change is made to the gitlab source files and pushed to master, puppet will run and the changes will be updated.

However this has stopped happening. My understanding is that the puppet master nodes will pull the changes from gitlab and then push it out to the puppet agent nodes that actually run the code.

I have been trying to work out where this has been broken but am really struggling.

I've done more digging and now in `/var/log/syslog` in the "agent" node

`puppet-agent[31231] Could not request certificate: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)`

I would guess this would be relevant.

If I run `sudo puppet agent --test`

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Fact file /var/lib/puppet/facts.d/factor was parsed but returned an empty data set
Fact file /var/lib/puppet/facts.d/puppet was parsed but returned an empty data set
Info: Caching catalog for {server-name}
Info: Applying configuration version 'XXXXXX'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 1.64 seconds
```

I can't tell if that actually calls out to the master node to check for new config?